# Is it possible to add custom buttons to mat select dropdown?

Tags: html, css, angular

Is it possible to add custom buttons (Ok and Cancel) like the photo below so that in a multi-select mat dropdown the user doesnt have to click outside the box to close the dropdown?

I didnt see this in the angular documentation

```
<h4>Basic native select</h4>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Cars</mat-label>
  <select matNativeControl required>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</mat-form-field>
```

[image]

here is the stackblitz of what I have so far
https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-all-option-angular-material?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Is it possible to share demo link?

Comment: added the stackblitz

Comment: something like this ? `https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-all-option-angular-material-6aexy8`

You need to handle events in this case

Comment: Yea that would work. Can you post this as an answer so you can get the bounty?

Comment: Added a version with basic event handling as well. Check if that suits you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a version with basic event handling as well

https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-all-option-angular-material-uvu3eb

#### Edit as requested by @Youp Bernoulli (2024-03-01)

This is achieved by injecting a `div` with Buttons inside the `mat-select` and binding them 2 callbacks to it

### Div and buttons

```
<mat-select placeholder="Projects" formControlName="project" multiple
            (selectionChange)="OnSelectChanged($event)" #matSelect>
            <app-select-check-all [model]="form.get('project')" [values]="projects">
            </app-select-check-all>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let project of projects" [value]="project">{{ project.name }}</mat-option>
    <hr>
<!-- Global overried for .mat-select-panel max-height at style.css -->
    <div class="row no-gutters pb-1">
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-right pr-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="okClicked()">Ok</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-right  pr-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="cancelClicked()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</mat-select>
```

### Binding

```
 okClicked() {
    this.last_selection = this.form.controls.project.value
    this.matSelect.close()
  }

  cancelClicked() {
    this.form.controls.project.setValue(this.last_selection)
    this.matSelect.close()
  }
```

Comment: without plugin, preferred.

Comment: Note that this option is not accessible, the user cannot reach the buttons using only the keyboard

Comment: Please provide the key code elements, to make the requested feature happen, in the answer.

Comment: @CCR Options are selectable using keyboard by pressing the options first letter on keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

You could make a 'fixed' footer by doing something like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(value)]="selected">
        <div class="custom-panel">
            <mat-option>None</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="option2">Option 2</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="option3">Option 3</mat-option>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <button mat-raised-button>Ok</button>
            <button mat-button>Cancel</button>
        </footer>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

and the css:

```
// This one must be in the global style (or ng-deep but it's deprecated :( )
.mat-select-panel{
  overflow: hidden !important;
}

footer{
  border-top:2px solid gray; 
  height: 44px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align:right;
}

.custom-panel {
  max-height: 200px; // mat-select-panel height = 256px. 200 + 10 + 44 + 2
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Here is [the repro on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q7gvor?file=src%2Fstyles.scss)

Try adding more options to see that the scrolling does not affect your button.

It also works like a charm on your stackblitz. I just changed 'footer' by a div with a class.

Comment: This solution will not work when there are no options.

Comment: Note that this option is not accessible, the user cannot reach the buttons using only the keyboard